# Letter / number combination in JSON (Google spreadsheet)

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-sheets-api

I need your help. I have written a small javascript that reads a Google spreadsheet. This spreadsheet is maintained by another employee. There are the following columns named last name (column A, as example "Doe"), first name (column B, as example "John"), a Chayns ID which is used for matching (column C, as example 112-73302) and a score which the person has achieved so far.

In the Chayns environment (A platform for various apps) I query the current Chayns ID, which is assigned when logged in. Matching the JSON file provided by Google is read and the score matching the Chayns ID is output accordingly. Now unfortunately something has changed in the Chayns system. The Chayns IDs used to consist of pure numbers, but now this has been replaced by a combination of numbers and letters. The script still works with pure number-based IDs, but no longer with the new IDs in combination with the letters. Now I'm wondering where I just got the thinking error. I tried to examine the JSON file provided by Google. Where the letter number combination should be output, there is only a "NULL". How can I work around this? I am not so fit in the topic JSON!

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
chayns.ready.then(() => {
    if (chayns.env.user.isAuthenticated) { // check if person is logged-in
        const chaynsid = chayns.env.user.personId; // Chayns-ID to variable
        const chaynsperson = chayns.env.user.name; // Chayns-Username to variable
        let chaynsBereinigt = chaynsid; // rename
        chaynsBereinigt = chaynsBereinigt.replace(/-/g, '');  // replace all dashes in Chayns-ID with nothing
        document.getElementById('idausspielung').innerHTML = chaynsid;
        const base = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/gviz/tq?'; // Google Sheets Info
        const output = document.querySelector('.output'); // Target is Html table with class output
        const query = encodeURI('Select D where C = ' + chaynsBereinigt); // Which columns should be output with
        const url = base + '&tq=' + query;
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(rep => {
                const data = JSON.parse(rep.substr(47).slice(0, -2));
                const row = document.createElement('tr');
                output.append(row);
                data.table.cols.forEach((heading) => {
                    const cell = document.createElement('td');
                    cell.textContent = heading.label;
                    row.append(cell);
                })
                data.table.rows.forEach((main) => {
                    const container = document.createElement('tr');
                    output.append(container);
                    main.c.forEach((ele) => {
                        const cell = document.createElement('td');
                        cell.textContent = ele.v;
                        container.append(cell);
                    })
                })
            })
        console.log("Hallo " + chaynsperson + " , deine Chayns-ID lautet: " + chaynsBereinigt); // Play out values to console
    }
})
```

```
JSON OUTPUT

// Correctly output values number-based
{"c":[{"v":"Doe"},{"v":"Francis"},{"v":5.0928467E7,"f":"50928467"},{"v":1028.0,"f":"1028"}]}

// Incorrectly output values number and letter based (example: 75VBUA3I)
{"c":[{"v":"Doe"},{"v":"Francis"},null,{"v":100.0,"f":"100"}]}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask]. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Why are you using `.text()` instead of `.json()`?

Comment: Can I ask you about the relationship between `JSON OUTPUT` and your showing script?

Comment: Hey Tanaike, of course! :) The Google spreadsheet file is addressed regarding the gviz addition in such a way that a JSON file is output there in real time, which is then processed. So I always take over the bonus employee points in real time. Here is a suitable link for this: https://ai2.metricrat.co.uk/guides/use-gviz-to-get-and-query-google-sheet-data

The question is why the JSON output of the Google Spreadsheet exports the mixture of letters and numbers as "NULL". There should be the error I can not understand right now!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: You don't have to apologize, I don't think my English is any better! :D The problem is this: In the past the Chayns IDs consisted only of numbers. In the meantime this has changed completely and there are letter-number combinations as Chayns IDs. The Chayns IDs and the corresponding employee points are provided as a JSON file. If the Chayns ID consists of pure numbers, everything works fine. If it is a combination of numbers and letters, it doesn't work at all! Then Google will output a "NULL" in the JSON file. And I really can't explain why! 1/2

Comment: I must say that I am not a programming professional and was already quite proud of my script, as I continue to try to think myself further and further into the subject, I would like to find the solution here. Thanks a lot for your help! :) 2/2

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. I apologize for this. For example, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue?